# Created pdf doesn't make line breaks using jsPDF()

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, jspdf

Im using jsPDF to create a pdf from a webpage. However, the text within <p>-tags end up on the same row, which means that some text gets outside the view.
How can I add new rows when the text gets long?

Here is the code:

```
function printPDF() {
    var doc = new jsPDF()
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");

    doc.fromHTML(myDiv, 10, 10)
    doc.save('a4.pdf')
}
```

and here is the result:
[image]

Comment: I was hoping to only have to use the fromHTML() function and not break it down into smaller parts. But I guess this could be a solution yes!

Comment: You must add the width, something like that: 
       pdf.fromHTML(YourData, 15, 15, {
          width: 180,
          });